# How to transform/reformat a csv file?

Tags: r, csv, unix

I have an oddly formatted csv file that is an output from an instrument I need data from with 672 lines. It has multiple samples and the output concentrations for chemical compounds arranged vertically. It looks something like this:

```
"Sample 1"
"Compound A", 1
"Compound B", 1
"Compound C", 1
"Sample 2"
"Compound A", 3
"Compound B", 3
"Compound C", 3
"Sample 3"
"Compound A", 2
"Compound B", 2
"Compound C", 2
```

I honestly don't know where to start as far as achieving this goal. I would normally do this type of transformation in R but the file format is still unwieldy when read into R.

In R, when reading in the csv file with:
        `Test <- read.csv("Test.csv", sep=",", header=FALSE)`

I get the following:

```
              V1      V2         
      1    Sample 1    NA   
      2    Compound A  1     
      3    Compound B  1   
      4    Compound C  1      
      5    Sample 2    NA     
      6    Compound A  3     
      7    Compound B  3       
      8    Compound C  3
      9    Sample 2    NA     
     10    Compound A  2     
     11    Compound B  2       
     12    Compound C  2
```

I am hoping to get an output file that has Samples as the columns and the Compounds as the rows with the correct concentrations for each. For example:

```
           Sample 1  Sample 2  Sample 3
Compound 1     1        3          2
Compound 2     1        3          2
Compound 3     1        3          2
```

So an R solution or a unix solution would work as I could write the dataframe to a text file and work with it in bash terminal.

Comment: "_the file format is offensive_"  -- what is wrong with it?   The extra spaces (after commas) and quotes are normally handled by good libraries. In Perl, it'd be [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV).  Then the rest is about rearranging data as you wish...

Comment: Are those quotes literal quotes in the file?

Comment: I also don't see how your expected output matches to the given input; you go from 27 concentration values in the input to 9 in the output

Comment: @zdim, R is parsing the file fine, but the format it ends up in is difficult to work with in R, but I think you're right, I should just work within R or write the R file to a text file and work with that. I will untag perl here.

Comment: @zdim, thanks, I get what you mean, black boxes are sometimes unavoidable but probably not in this case. If you wouldn't mind sharing it though it might be educational :).

Comment: @CalumYou, yes those are actual quotes in the file, and thanks for pointing out the issues with concentrations! That was the old format before I cut it, bc I only care about the first concentration for each compound. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @zdim yes please! I think it'll be less confusing for others who use this question/solution. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: (done, left only the first one and your response to it is good to leave as well I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R is a good language for cleaning up the data, too.  I would do something like this:

```
df <- read.csv('/tmp/data', header=F)
v <- seq_len(nrow(df))
v[!is.na(df$V2)] <- NA
v <- zoo::na.locf(v)
df$sample <- df$V1[v]
df <- df[!is.na(df$V2),]
```

That uses `zoo::na.locf` for the main task, which I always find to be a good option when the contents of one row have to influence subsequent rows.

Now you have a `data.frame` with a column containing the sample numbers:

```
           V1 V2   sample
2  Compound A  1 Sample 1
3  Compound B  1 Sample 1
4  Compound C  1 Sample 1
6  Compound A  3 Sample 2
7  Compound B  3 Sample 2
8  Compound C  3 Sample 2
10 Compound A  2 Sample 3
11 Compound B  2 Sample 3
12 Compound C  2 Sample 3
```

Using one of the options for 'tall' to 'wide' format should get you the rest of the way there:

```
> reshape(df, idvar='V1', direction='wide', timevar='sample')
          V1 V2.Sample 1 V2.Sample 2 V2.Sample 3
2 Compound A           1           3           2
3 Compound B           1           3           2
4 Compound C           1           3           2
```

Comment: Thanks @Ken Williams that works perfectly, I didn't know about the zoo package!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` method of accomplishing the same cleaning in R. We can:

1. `read_lines` the file to get a character vector with one line per element
2. `str_remove_all` the literal quotes in each line
3. Put the lines into a `tibble` (dataframe) column
4. `str_detect` whether each row is a Compound row with data, or just a Sample header. Use `cumsum` to mark the Compound rows with the right Sample number and then `filter` the headers out
5. `separate` the Compound identifiers from the concentration values
6. `spread` the data out into a wide format.

```r
library(tidyverse)
file <- read_lines(
'"Sample 1"
"Compound A", 1
"Compound B", 1
"Compound C", 1
"Sample 2"
"Compound A", 3
"Compound B", 3
"Compound C", 3
"Sample 3"
"Compound A", 2
"Compound B", 2
"Compound C", 2'
)
file %>%
  str_remove_all("\"") %>%
  tibble(line = .) %>%
  mutate(sample =  str_detect(line, "Sample") %>% cumsum %>% str_c("Sample_", .)) %>%
  filter(!str_detect(line, "Sample")) %>%
  separate(line, c("compound", "concentration"), sep = ", ") %>%
  spread(sample, concentration)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   compound   Sample_1 Sample_2 Sample_3
#>   <chr>      <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 Compound A 1        3        2       
#> 2 Compound B 1        3        2       
#> 3 Compound C 1        3        2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>